# How use SMS webservice in laravel?

Tags: web-services, laravel, sms, laravel-5

I have code that send SMS via webservice (for example sms class file), and i want use this code in laravel.
How can implement using this webservice in my app.

Comment: what service you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what do you mean exactly but here is a job class to send an SMS via plivo

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\User;
use Plivo\RestAPI;
class SendSms implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $sender;
    protected $list;

    public function __construct($sender,$list)
    {
         $this->sender = $sender;
         $this->list = $list;
         $this->from = env('plivo_from');
         $this->authid = env('plivo_authid');
         $this->token = env('plivo_token');
    }

    public function handle()
    {
         $auth_id = $this->authid;
         $auth_token = $this->token;
         $p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);
          Send a message
         $params = array(
                 'src' => $this->from, // Sender's phone number with country code
                 'dst' => $this->list, // receiver's phone number with country code
                 'text' => 'Hi, Message from Plivo' // Your SMS text message
             );
         // Send message
         $response = $p->send_message($params); 
// you can add more code to save error to db or something since this is a job, 

    }
}
```

then when you want to send sms just

```
 $this->dispatch(new SendSms($sender,$list);
```

You still can do this in a normal class/function but i hope you got the idea